# Minecraft sprinting while running and jumping

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have been playing on the same computer for about 5 years and it worked perfectly. Now for some reason I can not jump while running with sprint or just at all walking and jumping. I try to do it and I just jump in place. I tried changing version and it did not work. I try to run and jump and it goes well for about 1 or half a second and then I jump in place with no movement at all for like 5 seconds and that has been happening for about 2 weeks now. On all servers. I didn't change anything in my computer, version or buttons. It just started happening out of nowhere.  What do I do?

Comment: If you temporarily change your "jump" to left/right click (just for testing) does it fix it? I'm curious if this is a game issue or a hardware issue.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino yes, I don't think it's a game issue, most probably, his keyboard stopped working properly ig.

Answer (score 1):

Check your controls in Minecraft. It could be that the jump control is the same as your walking/sprinting controls.

Comment: I didnt change them, and i checked. Its ok. And it sometimes works and sometimes doesnt

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why that is happening but try reinstalling the game.

Comment: it honestly could be just a keyboard issue. I have had problems with keyboards in the past where they type the same letter twice or omit the letter completely.